# Debugger automation/scripting on Linux?

Tags: linux, debugging

I have a small C++ program that parses a file given as a command line argument. I want to create couple of test files and feed them to the program to make sure it does not crash when it reads malfomed files. I am looking to automate this process as I will have couple of hundred test files, either through GDB or something else.

Any tips?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `bash` or `python` for such scripts. For debugging you can just turn on core dump files generation and check what went wrong after the test is done.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm looking at "man core" right now. Any ideea if the dump file will contain the command line arguments? It's important that I get the file that caused the problem.

Comment: 1. It should contain this information
2. You can always check return code from your test script and output the command line parameters and newly generated core file name
3. Another option is to run your application under `gdb` and your script will stop if you'll get an error